# How to set the maximum size of BWidget's ScrolledWindow?

Tags: scrollbar, tcl, tk-toolkit, bwidget

I am using `BWidget`'s `ScrolledWindow` in a code like this:

```
toplevel .top
set w [ScrolledWindow .top.scrolledWindow]
set f [ScrollableFrame $w.scrollableFrame -constrainedwidth true]
$w setwidget $f
set a [$f getframe]
# here goes some stuff in $a
```

So I get a window with vertical scrollbar. When increasing the height of `.top`, after some moment all the content in `$a` becomes visible and the scrollbar disappears as it is not needed anymore. How can I forbid further increasing the height of `.top`? i.e. I need to set the maximum height of `.top` to the value when all content of $a is visible. How can I do that ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Many users (count me as one!) absolutely detest windows that can't be resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the maximum height of a toplevel, you use [`wm maxsize`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/wm.htm#M40), possibly with a very large value for the horizontal size. To get the current size of it, you use [`winfo height`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/winfo.htm#M16) (and `winfo width` in the other dimension). Combining these:

```
# 10k is just a "big" number
wm maxsize .top 10000 [winfo height .top]
```

Now, the tricky bit with BWidget is that it doesn't set the size of the window immediately, or even on first display. This means that you have to put in a guess about when to configure the window. A cheap thing to try is to put it half a second in the future; after all, even expert users are likely to spend at least a little while looking before interacting with it. That's done with [`after`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/after.htm#M6) like this:

```
# 500 milliseconds in the future
after 500 {
    # 10k is just a "big" number
    wm maxsize .top 10000 [winfo height .top]
}
```